# MongoDB Find All Comments

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have several documents that use the following structure:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f9c6fe033cddec1bea430f2"), 
  "title" : "Product #1",
  "comments" : 
  [
  {
    "comment" : "My comment",  
    "date" : "2012-03-01 00: 00: 00",   
    "name" : "Test Name",   
    "username" : "Test Username"
  },
  {
    "comment" : "My comment",  
    "date" : "2012-03-01 00: 00: 00",   
    "name" : "Test Name 2",   
    "username" : "Test Username 2"
  }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible for me to find all documents that have reviews.name and update it? For example say I want to find all documents with user.name : test name 2 and change it to Cassie. Is that possible? If not would it be better to put the comments in a different collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You would have to use `comments.username` to find it and then `comments.$.username` note that since you are posting to an array you have to tell mongo to go in there using the [$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)